# Redraw svg rect on mouse hover

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, vivus

I want to redraw my rectangles on mouse hover.

For now i have this in my html :

```
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 210 297" version="1.1"
    id="svg8" inkscape:version="0.92.0 r15299" sodipodi:docname="dessin.svg">
    <rect id="rect3680" width="128.5119" height="21.922617" x="38.55357" y="75.505951" style="stroke-width:0.26458332" />
    <rect id="rect3684" width="91.470238" height="23.434523" x="40.065475" y="117.08333" style="stroke-width:0.26458332" />
    <rect id="rect3686" width="127" height="24.190477" x="40.065475" y="160.17262" style="stroke-width:0.26458332;" />
</svg>
```

I want to do this using only css attributes at best. For now I can only change the width of the rect from its original size to another using transition attribute.

I tried to use vivus library but it didn't work.

Thanks.

```css
#rect3680:hover {
    fill: tomato;
    width: 300px;
    transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
        xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 210 297" version="1.1"
        id="svg8" inkscape:version="0.92.0 r15299" sodipodi:docname="dessin.svg">
        <rect id="rect3680" width="128.5119" height="21.922617" x="38.55357" y="75.505951" style="stroke-width:0.26458332" />
        <rect id="rect3684" width="91.470238" height="23.434523" x="40.065475" y="117.08333" style="stroke-width:0.26458332" />
        <rect id="rect3686" width="127" height="24.190477" x="40.065475" y="160.17262" style="stroke-width:0.26458332;" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have code that works, so what are you asking?

Comment: Note that the ability to style geometric attributes - like the `width` of a rectangle - is a thing that has been added to the SVG2 specification.  As of writing, only Chrome supports that.  If you want it to work cross browser, you will need to use a JS animation library.  If that is what you are asking, then please update your question to make that clear.